# Create SQL Function view with User ID and Date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, datetime, view

As I title says, I need to create a Function View of two tables.

Below are the SQL Tables

```
CREATE TABLE User_Specialist(
        ID_User_Specialist      INT         NOT NULL,
        Name_User_Specialist    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK_ID_User_Specialist    PRIMARY KEY(ID_User_Specialist),
GO

CREATE TABLE Incident(
    ID_Incident                 INT         IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    Incident_Creation_Date      DATETIME                    NULL,
    Assigned_Specialist         INT                         NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Assigned_Specialist   FOREIGN KEY (Especialista_Asignado) REFERENCES Usuario_Especialista(ID_Usuario_Especialista),
GO
```

Based on the previous information, I need the function to display Assign Specialist and the dates that the **Incident** was created.

Right know this is what I got:

```
CREATE FUNCTION View_Date (@ID_User_Incident INT)
    RETURNS INT
      AS
        BEGIN 
          DECLARE @Total_Incidents INT
            SELECT @Total_Incidents = COUNT(ID_Incident)
              FROM Incidents i, User_Specialist u
            WHERE i.ID_Incident = u.ID_User_Specialist AND u.ID_User_Specialist =@ID_User_Incident 
          RETURN (@Total_Incidents)
        END
GO

DECLARE @Specialist_ID int;
EXEC @Specialist_ID = [dbo].View_Date
    @ID_Incidentes_Usuarios = 5;
SELECT @Specialist_ID AS 'Assigned Specialist Incidents'
GO
```

The only thing missing is the dates range.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Currently Using SSMS 2017 (SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: @AarónHenríquez  If you want to see total incidents, first incident date and last incident date related with assigned specialist you need to change your function to Table function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you changed your table and field names to English from Spanish. You have missed some of them and there were some missing parenthesis. As much as I understand I changed them to understand better.

```
CREATE TABLE User_Specialist
(
        ID_User_Specialist      INT         NOT NULL,
        Name_User_Specialist    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_ID_User_Specialist  PRIMARY KEY(ID_User_Specialist)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Incident
(
    ID_Incident                 INT         IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    Incident_Creation_Date      DATETIME                    NULL,
    Assigned_Specialist         INT                         NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_Assigned_Specialist   FOREIGN KEY (Assigned_Specialist) REFERENCES User_Specialist(ID_User_Specialist)
)
GO
```

If you want to see multiple columns or rows as result you need to use `Table-valued Function`. I have created sample query from your table and prepared function. you can change it with what you want.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_ViewDate
(
    @ID_User_Incident INT
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE 
(
     TotalIncidents     INT
    ,FirstIncidentDate  DATETIME
    ,LastIncidentDate   DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Result
    SELECT   COUNT(ID_Incident)
            ,MIN(Incident_Creation_Date)
            ,MAX(Incident_Creation_Date)
    FROM Incident I
    LEFT JOIN User_Specialist U ON I.Assigned_Specialist = U.ID_User_Specialist
    WHERE I.Assigned_Specialist = @ID_User_Incident 

    RETURN 
END
GO
```

Comment: Fast question as it is the first time I use a Function table.
How do you do to insert values to confirm shown the table information?

Comment: @AarónHenríquez , sorry I couldn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can help you.

```
declare @count int = 0 , @dates varchar(200) ='' 
  SELECT  @count+=1 , @dates +=' '+ i.Incident_Creation_Date      
              FROM Incidents i, User_Specialist u
            WHERE i.ID_Incident = u.ID_User_Specialist AND u.ID_User_Specialist =@ID_User_Incident 

            select @count as [count] ,@dates [incidentDates]
```